# About best practices of JMS integration using TIBCO .Net client

Tags: .net, integration, tibco

I'm working on an integration project where I'm talking to JMS framework using TIBCO .Net client.
A colleague is recommdending a design decision based on a fear of receiving too many messages suddenly in a way that our application can't handle it. We are using Asynchronous mode while receiving messages. I'm new to that topic so I couldn't find quick best practices to support his clam or mine. Any suggestions? How can I test this subject?

Answer (score 1):

After I tested the subject for a while I found out there's no fear of number of received messages. The major point won't be in receiving itself but in the processing of received message. This is what determines the actual performance of application.

In a previous design, We have separated the Receiver component from Processor component & That resulted in delay because we have to wait till receiver finishes then to start processing received messages via the another component.

This design is being changed now. So, processing should be immediately upon a message reception. Message receiving should be Asynchronously through handling the event MessageHandler of type EMSMessageHandler and this is the best practice for message receiving so far.